# batch start programs and hit enter in windows 7

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, uac, windows-7-x64

I have 4 programs I frequently open when I'm doing development. I didn't feel like actually doing some development one evening so I wrote this script:

*test.bat*

```
start /d "C:\eclipse" eclipse.exe
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin" pidgin.exe
start /d "C:\wamp" wampmanager.exe
start /wait /d "E:\websites\scripts" tunnelier.vbs
```

*tunnelier.vbs*

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise Tunnelier\Tunnelier.exe"""
WshShell.AppActivate "Tunnelier"

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

and I'm finding that it successfully opens all of the programs, but there are two problems.

1. The enter key is not being sent while tunnelier is the active window (it doesn't login.) If I just run tunnelier.vbs it works fine, but in the batch file it doesn't work.
2. wampmanager.exe must have an odd manifest file because windows is giving me that annoying and long-winded "do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to your computer" prompt.

So my question is twofold;

1. How can I make the enter key register in the proper window?
2. How can I get rid of the unknown publisher UAC prompt?

I've tried to research both topics and have failed, so any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You don't need to send enter key. Start the Tunnelier specifying `-profile` and `-loginOnStartup`, this also means you don't need VBScript script anymore.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise Tunnelier\Tunnelier.exe -profile=profile_file.path -loginOnStartup

Also check out : http://www.bitvise.com/files/tunnelier-params.txt

- To get rid of UAC for wampmanager, you can use [Runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx). It prompts password for every call but not with **/savecred** parameter, however you have to enter the password for once.

Finally, your script could be something like that:

```
start /d "C:\eclipse" eclipse.exe
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin" pidgin.exe
start runas /profile /savecred /user:Administrator "c:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise Tunnelier" Tunnelier.exe -profile=profile_file.path -loginOnStartup
```

Comment: how clever are you that you realized that's what I was trying to do. Kudos, and thank you very much. I figured it had params, but couldn't find a list for some reason.

Comment: this seems to be working except the wampmanager.exe password prompt. When I enter it; nothing happens. I imagine that my user account password will not work here. I don't recall setting up an administrator password - would Windows 7 installer just generate one randomly?

Comment: @AlexWaters You're welcome. No, set an administrator password then try again.

Comment: Ok I set the administrator password. Unfortunately all that happens is a CMD window opens and closes quickly. I opened up CMD.exe and when I input: start runas /profile /savecred /user:Administrator "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe" it briefly opens a CMD.exe window.

Comment: If I do start "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"  it opens a CMD.exe window with the title C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe maybe the problem is related to this?

Comment: I never used Wamp, so I installed it, I saw it is a win-form application and script ran properly for me. As another option you can try to set start the application as an administrator always manually through http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx If it works, a command like `start /d "C:\wamp\" wampmanager.exe` in the script will be sufficient.

Comment: I tried to run the command on another program, and the same thing happens =(

Comment: Trying to diagnose and solve that problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036659/why-cant-i-start-programs-in-the-command-line-without-d-windows-7x64

Comment: There seems to be some confusion with the quotes :)

Comment: can you paste the command you used with /profile /user:Administrator to get wamp running?

Comment: @AlexWaters Just `start runas /profile /savecred /user:Administrator "c:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"` as in the answer. I ran through the batch script.