# Why can't I start programs in the command line without /d? (Windows 7x64)

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, dos

I am trying to create a batch script that opens a program. I am doing some testing and I can't figure this out:

If I run CMD.exe and input `start /d "C:\wamp" wampmanager.exe` the program opens

but

If I run CMD.exe and input `start "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"` I get "the current directory is invalid"

Now when I try to do `start runas /profile /user:Administrator "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"` I get prompted for Administrator's password, but nothing happens when I enter it.

Can someone please tell me how I can run the above command?

Comment: I have tested this problem with other programs, it's not Wamp specific

Comment: What directory are you in when you issue the `start` command?

Comment: When I run cmd.exe it shows C:\Users\Alex>  as the default path. I would like to run this command: start runas /profile /user:Administrator "C:\Program Files (x86)\iSpy\iSpy\iSpy.exe" or start runas /profile /user:Administrator "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe" ... neither are working =(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the start program's syntax expect the window title as its first *quoted* argument.
(see `start /?`). You can supply an empty string, however:

```
start "" "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe"
```

or, if you don't need quotes to mask parts of the path, just leave them out altogether:

```
start C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe
```

Comment: I tried start "" runas /profile /user:Administrator "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe" but nothing happens

Comment: Typing it in cmd it opens a new console window asking the Administrator password, then starts the program. You might need to specify the domain name as well: runas /user:domain\Administrator.

Comment: I tried the above, and nothing happens. It opens a window requesting the password, but when I enter the password the window just disappears. WAMP doesn't start =(.

Comment: If I do start "" "C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe" - it starts, but prompts me to allow unknown publisher =(

Comment: I have seen here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/19/how-to-bypass-the-security-warning-unknown-publisher-with-the-checkbox-always-ask-before-opening-this-file.aspx an article suggesting to add the UNC paths to Local Intranet or Trusted Sites.

Answer (score 0):

```
start "some-text"
```

starts a new command window with "some-text" as the title of the window. To start a program, do not use the quotes around the argument

```
start program-name
```

Comment: That tells only half the story, though because sometimes you have to quote.

Comment: If you do have to quote (for ex, if the path contains spaces) then: start "" "program-name". The basic issue is the first quoted parameter that in @Alex's command is taken as window title. So if the path does not have any spaces (the winamp example he has specifically mentioned), then the simple solution I have stated will work.

Comment: I know that. That was just a hint to you that "Just don't use quotes" is only half helpful.

Comment: start runas /profile /user:Administrator C:\wamp\wampmanager.exe also does not work

Comment: Both start "" runas ... and start runas ... work for me. What do you see? You should get a command prompt asking for Administrator password.

Comment: I do get that command prompt, but nothing happens after I enter the password. The windows just disappears and WAMP doesn't load